# google vision OCR returning too much information

Tags: c#, api, google-api, google-vision

I created a simple class to test out googles vision OCR API. I am passing in a simple image with 5 letters that should return a string with "CRAIG" in it. Although this API call returns a lot of extra information:

```
{
    "property": {
        "detectedLanguages": [
            {
                "languageCode": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
    "boundingBox": {
        "vertices": [
            {
                "x": 183,
                "y": 105
            },
            {
                "x": 674,
                "y": 105
            },
            {
                "x": 674,
                "y": 253
            },
            {
                "x": 183,
                "y": 253
            }
        ]
    },
    "symbols": [
        {
            "property": {
                "detectedLanguages": [
                    {
                        "languageCode": "en"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "vertices": [
                    {
                        "x": 183,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 257,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 257,
                        "y": 253
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 183,
                        "y": 253
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "C",
            "confidence": 0.99
        },
        {
            "property": {
                "detectedLanguages": [
                    {
                        "languageCode": "en"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "vertices": [
                    {
                        "x": 249,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 371,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 371,
                        "y": 253
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 249,
                        "y": 253
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "R",
            "confidence": 0.99
        },
        {
            "property": {
                "detectedLanguages": [
                    {
                        "languageCode": "en"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "vertices": [
                    {
                        "x": 459,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 581,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 581,
                        "y": 253
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 459,
                        "y": 253
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "A",
            "confidence": 0.99
        },
        {
            "property": {
                "detectedLanguages": [
                    {
                        "languageCode": "en"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "vertices": [
                    {
                        "x": 582,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 638,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 638,
                        "y": 253
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 582,
                        "y": 253
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "I",
            "confidence": 0.98
        },
        {
            "property": {
                "detectedLanguages": [
                    {
                        "languageCode": "en"
                    }
                ],
                "detectedBreak": {
                    "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "vertices": [
                    {
                        "x": 636,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 674,
                        "y": 105
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 674,
                        "y": 253
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 636,
                        "y": 253
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "G",
            "confidence": 0.99
        }
    ],
    "confidence": 0.98
}
```

How can I get only the letters returned instead?

class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string credential_path = @"C:\Users\35385\nodal.json";
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credential_path);

        // Instantiates a client
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        // Load the image file into memory
        var image = Image.FromFile("vision.jpg");
        // Performs label detection on the image file
        var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);

        foreach (var page in response.Pages)
        {
            foreach (var block in page.Blocks)
            {
                foreach (var paragraph in block.Paragraphs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", paragraph.Words));
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

The image I passed in was a simple word that I drew out in paint:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: it was just a simple word written in paint: https://i.ibb.co/9Hj7qb5/vision.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researching, the following provides me with the word and also a much cleaner output:

```
Block Text at (183, 105) - (674, 105) - (674, 253) - (183, 253)
  Paragraph at (183, 105) - (674, 105) - (674, 253) - (183, 253)
    Word: CRAIG
```

method:

```
foreach (var page in response.Pages)
            {
                foreach (var block in page.Blocks)
                {
                    string box = string.Join(" - ", block.BoundingBox.Vertices.Select(v => $"({v.X}, {v.Y})"));
                    Console.WriteLine($"Block {block.BlockType} at {box}");
                    foreach (var paragraph in block.Paragraphs)
                    {
                        box = string.Join(" - ", paragraph.BoundingBox.Vertices.Select(v => $"({v.X}, {v.Y})"));
                        Console.WriteLine($"  Paragraph at {box}");
                        foreach (var word in paragraph.Words)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"    Word: {string.Join("", word.Symbols.Select(s => s.Text))}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing..

```
var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
```

To

```
var response = client.DetectText(image);
```

**Explanation**

Here are some information from GOOGLE CLOUD VISION API docs

The Vision API can detect and extract text from images. There are two annotation features that support optical character recognition (OCR):

- TEXT_DETECTION detects and extracts text from any image. For example, a photograph might contain a street sign or traffic sign. The JSON includes the entire extracted string, as well as individual words, and their bounding boxes.
- DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION also extracts text from an image, but the response is optimized for dense text and documents. The JSON includes page, block, paragraph, word, and break information.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I will need to use detect document text in my application

Comment: What the exact output u want..?

Comment: i created a new question with my full requirements if you would like to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736076/extracting-data-from-specific-image-locations-using-google-vision-ocr-api